# Firebase iOS app restore view

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I made an app with 3 views for to explain my problem:

1. The first is the view for the login.
2. The second view show a table with several informations.
3. The third view will open when user select an item from the `UITableView`.

I've installed Firebase (using Cocoapods) because I want to receive push notifications in my app. The problem is that when I have the third view open and if I press the home button and the app goes to background, when I go back to my app it restarts from the first view with login.

I think that this behaviour is bound to the use of Firebase. In fact, if I delete the pod and try reopening the app from the background again, I see the last view and not the first.

How can I save and restore the view?

Do I have to do it in the `AppDelegate` with `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillEnterForeground`?

Comment: I don't see how Firebase could be the culprit for anything like this. You should show some code.

Comment: Agreed. This is unrelated to Firebase itself. However, depending on your code, it could be tied in. i.e. if you have some code that executes inside an observe closure, it could technically pull  up the first view after Firebase returns with data. That being said, this is way to vague for anyone to answer.